# What's causing these ParseError exceptions when reading off an AWS SQS queue in my Storm cluster

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, apache-storm, jaxp

I'm using Storm 0.8.1 to read incoming messages off an Amazon SQS queue and am getting consistent exceptions when doing so:

```
2013-12-02 02:21:38 executor [ERROR] 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to unmarshall response (ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: JAXP00010001: The parser has encountered more than "64000" entity expansions in this document; this is the limit imposed by the JDK.)
        at REDACTED.spouts.SqsQueueSpout.handleNextTuple(SqsQueueSpout.java:219)
        at REDACTED.spouts.SqsQueueSpout.nextTuple(SqsQueueSpout.java:88)
        at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3976$fn__4017$fn__4018.invoke(executor.clj:447)
        at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__465.invoke(util.clj:377)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to unmarshall response (ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: JAXP00010001: The parser has encountered more than "64000" entity expansions in this document; this is the limit imposed by the JDK.)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:524)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:298)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:167)
        at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:812)
        at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.receiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:575)
        at REDACTED.spouts.SqsQueueSpout.handleNextTuple(SqsQueueSpout.java:191)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: JAXP00010001: The parser has encountered more than "64000" entity expansions in this document; this is the limit imposed by the JDK.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.setInputSource(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:219)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.<init>(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:189)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl.getXMLStreamReaderImpl(XMLInputFactoryImpl.java:277)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl.createXMLStreamReader(XMLInputFactoryImpl.java:129)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl.createXMLEventReader(XMLInputFactoryImpl.java:78)
        at com.amazonaws.http.StaxResponseHandler.handle(StaxResponseHandler.java:85)
        at com.amazonaws.http.StaxResponseHandler.handle(StaxResponseHandler.java:41)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:503)
        ... 10 more
```

I've debugged the data on the queue and everything looks good. I can't figure out why the API's XML response would be causing these problems. Any ideas?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Answering my own question here for the ages.

There's currently an XML expansion limit processing bug in Oracle and OpenJDK's Java that results in a shared counter hitting the default upper bound when parsing multiple XML documents.

1. https://blogs.oracle.com/joew/entry/jdk_7u45_aws_issue_123
2. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8028111
3. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/123

Although I thought that our version (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.4) wasn't affected, running the sample code given in the OpenJDK bug report did indeed verify that we were susceptible to the bug.

To work around the issue, I needed to pass `jdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit=0` to the Storm workers. By adding the following to `storm.yaml` across my cluster, I was able to mitigate this problem.

```
supervisor.childopts: "-Djdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit=0"
worker.childopts: "-Djdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit=0"
```

I should note that this technically opens you up to a Denial of Service attack, but since our XML documents are only coming from SQS, I'm not worried about someone forging malevolent XML to kill our workers.

Comment: There might be more to this.  I am getting the same error using Java6.  I do not have Java7 installed anywhere on my machine.

Comment: P.S.  Outstanding Post by the way.

Comment: Never mind.  Found this also effects specific versions of Java5, 6, 7, and8.  See this for details
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8028111

Comment: Hi all, I have solved the problem by simply adding the line 'System.setProperty("jdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit", "0");' to my program. Strangely enough the problem was still occurring when using the parameter passed to the program as an argument from the command line.

Comment: According to java documentation, setting the value for "jdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit" property to "0" acts as no limit. You should use a negative value to disable the entity expansion. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/limits/limits.html