# Extend parser limit of external java library

Tags: java, xml-parsing, rdf, owl

In my java project I use an external library (Semantic Measures Library) which uses an external parser. Whenever I try to run large datasets this external Library throws

> The parser has encountered more than "100,000" entity expansions in this document; this is the limit imposed by the application.

I have tried

```
-DentityExpansionLimit=100000000
```

and

```
-DentityExpansionLimit=0
```

(the same for `-Djdk.xml.totalEntitySizeLimit` and `-Djdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit=0`).
 I have also tried to change the type of input files as suggested to me.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20482332/6730571) says you need to pass `-Djdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit=0`, which I don't see in the attempts you mentioned.

Comment: I am sorry Hugues, I have tried that too.. I farily new to coding but I believe that the problem is that this commands are not being used by the library. My project works with large inputs (without the library) and works just fine with smaller inputs (using the library).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's causing these ParseError exceptions when reading off an AWS SQS queue in my Storm cluster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482331/whats-causing-these-parseerror-exceptions-when-reading-off-an-aws-sqs-queue-in)

Comment: Do you know which external parser that is, and which class name? That might suggest possibilities.