# Unable to unmarshall response (Missing type parameter.). Response Code: 200, Response Text: OK

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services

I am trying to make an app on Android.
When I set minifyEnabled to true, I get this error :

```
E/Lex: InteractiveVoiceViewAdapter: Interaction error                                               
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to unmarshall response (Missing type parameter.). Response Code: 200, Response Text: OK
                                                    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleResponse(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.amazonaws.services.lexrts.AmazonLexRuntimeClient.invoke(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.amazonaws.services.lexrts.AmazonLexRuntimeClient.postContent(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.lex.interactionkit.InteractionClient$2.run(Unknown Source)
                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter.
                                                    at com.b.c.c.a.getSuperclassTypeParameter(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.b.c.c.a.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.amazonaws.services.lexrts.model.transform.PostContentResultJsonUnmarshaller$1.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.amazonaws.services.lexrts.model.transform.PostContentResultJsonUnmarshaller.unmarshall(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.amazonaws.services.lexrts.model.transform.PostContentResultJsonUnmarshaller.unmarshall(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.amazonaws.http.JsonResponseHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.amazonaws.http.JsonResponseHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
```

How to fix this? It works fine when minify is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not due to you set `minifyEnabled` to true. There is some problem on `Amazone AWS` configuration check out below details which help you to resolve your problem :

Looks like im reaching a XML expansion limit when building the initial list of documents to be indexed. Im trying to index around 6 million documents.

I edited /etc/init.d/elasticsearch and set `ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Djdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit=0"` which seems to have fixed the issue.

Reference: [What's causing these ParseError exceptions when reading off an AWS SQS queue in my Storm cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482331/whats-causing-these-parseerror-exceptions-when-reading-off-an-aws-sqs-queue-in)